# Django complex query for a leaderboard using Q

Tags: python, django-rest-framework, django-q

My models are like this:

```
class User(AbstractUser):
    ...

class UserPoints(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, relative_name='points')
    earned_points= models.IntegerField()
    reward_month = models.IntegerField(default=0)
    reward_year = models.IntegerField(default=0)
```

The `UserRewards` are created every month. I am using Q to generate queries.

What I want to do is make a list top 10 users, arranged according to sum of `earned_points`. The `UserRewards` will be filtered to only contain last three months worth. I know how to individually perform filter, aggregate, annotate and Sum. But in a single query or combining two queries, I can't seem to figure it out exactly, especially when there are multiple `UserRewards` per user.

Comment: Is `UserPoints` what you're referring to as `UserRewards`? What have you tried so far?

Answer (score 1):

I've fixed your model to have an `on_delete` attribute and corrected `relative_name` to `related_name` like this:

```
class UserPoints(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, related_name='points', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    earned_points = models.IntegerField()
    reward_month = models.IntegerField(default=0)
    reward_year = models.IntegerField(default=0)
```

Then I added some test data:

```
>>> up = UserPoints(user=User.objects.get(pk=1), earned_points=10, reward_month=2, reward_year=2021)
>>> up.save()
>>> up = UserPoints(user=User.objects.get(pk=1), earned_points=15, reward_month=1, reward_year=2021)
>>> # up assignment and up.save() omitted from here on...
>>> UserPoints(user=User.objects.get(pk=2), earned_points=5, reward_month=1, reward_year=2021)
>>> UserPoints(user=User.objects.get(pk=3), earned_points=7, reward_month=2, reward_year=2021)
>>> UserPoints(user=User.objects.get(pk=3), earned_points=3, reward_month=1, reward_year=2021)
```

Now we can sum and rank over `UserPoints` from `User` like this:

```
from django.db.models import Sum
for user in User.objects.all() \
        .annotate(earned_points_sum=Sum('points__earned_points')) \
        .filter(earned_points_sum__gt=0) \
        .order_by('-earned_points_sum'):
    print(user.pk, user.earned_points_sum)
```

That outputs:

```
1 25
3 10
2 5
```